# How to resolve Stanford Charniak Parser dependency

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, charniak-parser

I am trying to run the Charniak parser provided in `stanford-corenlp-1.3.5.jar`.  The package for the record is `edu.stanford.nlp.parser.charniak` and the class `CharniakParser`.

So I will give a code example of how I am trying to use it just for completeness:

```
CharniakParser cp = new CharniakParser();
PTBTokenizer<HasWord> ptbt = new PTBTokenizer(new FileReader("sample1.txt"), new WordTokenFactory(), "");
List<Word> tokens = new ArrayList<Word>();
for (Word token; ptbt.hasNext(); ) {
    token = (Word) ptbt.next();
    tokens.add(token);
}
Tree t = cp.getBarseParse(tokens);
```

On the last line there when running this code , I get

`cannot run program "/u/nlp/packages/bllip-parser/reranking-parser.sh" ... The system cannot find the specified file`

The problem is the human cannot find the specified file either.  I do not see that included in the distribution and I cannot find a dependency that I might need to download with that name.  A Google search reveals that the only place a 'reranking-parser.sh' exists is in the actual source code for Stanford's version of Charniak parser (I am trying hard to be clear because I know Stanford did not originally create the Charniak parser, it is from Brown).

So, does anyone have experience with this parser? What is missing?  I like my chances better on SO, so I ask here.

Comment: Mind creating a short tag wiki for [tag:charniak-parser]? It's a good tag, just not very self-descriptive.

Comment: @Telthien Yes, actually it slipped my mind ... thanks I will do it

Comment: I imagine the mailing lists shown at the bottom of this page will help you more. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, ok, @DMoses et al.  I subscribed to the mailing list and I got my answer as to what needs to be done.  So let me pass it along as answer for future visitors since it is not documented (until now):

The file `reranking-parser.sh` belongs to a *particular* version of the Charniak parser.  So you need to get *that version* of the parser which is on github and called "bllip-parser".  There is no official support in CoreNLP for the Charniak parser, nor is the functionality provided meant to be standalone, rather it is a student extension meant to work with the external parser from github.

A fairly simple procedure really to point to the C++ executable, but this does not work for me because at this point I would be using Python to call Java to call C++.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the [CoreNLP's code for CharniakParser.java](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/charniak/CharniakParser.java) has a hardcoded path in it. To use the parser, you'd probably need to edit the source to point it to [parse-50best.sh in the Charniak parser distribution](https://github.com/BLLIP/bllip-parser/blob/master/parse-50best.sh) (which would need to be downloaded separately from Stanford CoreNLP -- see the BLLIP Parser GitHub project in the second link).